# MySQL Fill a column with a regex based on others columns

Tags: mysql, regex

I would like to fill a column IF it is NULL with a regex. It is a email column, and I want to fill it with the : table.name+"."+table.firstname+"@"+"gmail.com" .

I tried something like this :

```
UPDATE table
SET 
    mail = table.name+"."+table.firstname+"@gmail.com"
WHERE mail IS NULL ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your set you have to concatenate the string which is tricky since thats what you were trying to do. MySQL decided to be different and make their own CONCAT function for string concatenation.

```
SET mail = CONCAT(t.name, '.', t.firstname, '@gmail.com')
```

mysql doesn't support string concatenation with `+`

so your whole query would be

```
UPDATE t
    SET mail = CONCAT(t.name, '.', t.firstname, '@gmail.com')
    WHERE mail IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with **CONCAT**

```
UPDATE table
SET 
    mail = CONCAT(table.name,".",table.firstname,"@gmail.com")
WHERE mail IS NULL ;
```

Comment: Ok, here is what i missed. Thanx you both, it works just fine.